# Dataframes within list within list - how to access each dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm pretty new to R, so please bear with me.

I read in an Excel spreadsheet containing 31 years of MLB prospect data on separate sheets using the following code:

```
path = "../Documents/BA Prospects 1990-2021.xlsx"
prospect_data <- excel_sheets(path = path) %>% 
  map(~ data.frame(read_excel(path, sheet = .)))
```

I then wrote a function to clean up the data a bit, and applied it to all 31 elements:

```
pull_df <- function(data, n = 1, year = 1990) {
    prospect_data[[n]] %>%
        data.frame() %>%
        filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
        mutate(year = year) %>% 
        select(year, everything())
}

prospect_data <- lapply(prospect_data[1:31], pull_df)
```

What I want is to take the 31 dataframes and save each one globally. However, those dataframes are each nested within a separate list. Those 31 lists are nested within the list prospect_data. No matter what I try, with for loops and all, I can't extract those dataframes from the prospect_data list to be able to manipulate them further. Honestly, I'd settle for one big data frame with 3100 rows and 17 columns at this point. I just want to get my data into a dataframe.

I know I did a poor job of explaining it, but please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to create individual dataframes in the global  environment. Using lists is a better idea or if you prefer combine them in one big dataframe. Also `length(1990:2021)` gives 32 values so I have adjusted below answer to use `1990:2020` instead if you in total have 31 dataframes in `prospect_data`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

pull_df <- function(data, year) {
  data %>%
    filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.))) %>% 
    mutate(year = year) %>% 
    select(year, everything())
}

combine_df <- map2_df(prospect_data, 1900:2020, pull_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, `prospect_data` is a list of one-element lists, where the single element in each component list is a dataframe.

If this is the case, you can "flatten" prospect_data with:

```
flattened_prospect_data <- unlist(prospect_data, recursive = FALSE)
```

However, if prospect_data is a list of arbitrary length lists, where the dataframe of interest is at index `j` you can do the following.

```
flattened_prospect_data <- lapply(prospect_data, function(x) x[[j]])
```

If each dataframe is nested even deeper, say each one is the kth element, of the jth element, of the ith element of an element of prospect_data. Then you can perform recursive extraction with

```
flattened_prospect_data <- lapply(prospect_data, function(x) x[[c(i, j, k)]])
```

Once you have all the dataframes in a list you can assign them to a name by their year using

```
get_year <- function(df) unique(df$year)
create_name <- function(x) paste(x, "Prospects") # create_name(1990) returns "1990 Prospects"

df_names <- sapply(flattened_prospect_data, function(x) create_name(get_year(x)))
Map(function(x, y) assign(x,value = y, envir = .GlobalEnv), df_names, flattened_prospect_data)
```